# How can I perform mouse action on HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to draw a big circle on the canvas and some small filled circles on the big circle and I want to handle those small filled circles using mouse click. By clicking on that small circle I want to remove them from canvas. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is a place for specific questions about specific problems. It does not sound like you have done any research on this. Next time you post a question please make sure you check out [what types of questions not to post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Despite that, your best bet is probably to use a library such as [EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/easeljs).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this with the html5 canvas is to store a list of your clickable objects, then for every click loop through all of the objects and see if the mouse is within its drawn area.

```
$('#myCanvas').click(function (e) {
    //get the actual mouse x and y of the click location
    var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
        mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    // loop through all of the circles
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        //if the x and y of the click are within the area of the circle
        if (mouseX < circles[i].right && mouseX > circles[i].left && mouseY > circles[i].top && mouseY < circles[i].bottom) {
            //show a message with the number of the circle
            alert ('clicked circle ' + (i + 1));
        }
    }
});
```

So when I draw my circles I would be adding them to `var circles = []` array

http://jsfiddle.net/a97yv1n3/1/

Comment: Here is an EaselJS version, based on @Nate's example. It is somewhat simplified, and treats each circle+text as a single item. You can also listen for events directly on each circle, instead of having to determine what was clicked yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/bjjjw716/